# Best word to describe “historically used formally but no longer acceptable”?

Tags: historical-change

What is a good word to use to describe a word that was used in history but now is becoming obsolete in literature *because* of its racial, cultural, or ethical bias implications?

For example, what is a good word to use to describe:

- Virginity (associated with the commodification of people especially women in that those who have not had sex are seen as more pure and desirable)
- Homosexual (appears neutral but is associated with derogatory projections of gay people. It is becoming replaced by the terms gay/same-sex orientation etc.)
- Nigger (while used still as a casual slang term amongst friends, the word is no longer acceptable in any form of public writing except when it is brought up to be discussed for its historical context).

Thanks!

EDIT: I want to edit this so that it’s clearer that maybe “obsolete” is not the best word here, as simply “being driven out of usage by its traditional context in formal literature” may describe what I’m looking for better. The term may still be used in slang or whatnot, but would not be considered prudent or even be considered offensive in formal conversation or literature.

Comment: "Archaic" comes close.

Comment: I need some help in understanding what you are asking for.   At first I thought you were talking about words which were what are called 'archaic' or ' archaisms':  that is words that have been in common use but have fallen out of use.  But you seem to be talking about words that have been widely used but which are now widely considered unacceptable.  Such a word will never be like archaisms, if only because they some could come back.  What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: Thanks Tuffy, the latter definition that you gave would be what I am looking for. Sorry that it’s not explicit in the question since I wanted to keep the word count lower.

Comment: It's not a single word and I don't think that there is a single word for this concept but you could call such words "no longer acceptable". This encapsulates the idea that the word used to acceptable and, as such, widely used but is now considered to be so offensive that polite people do not use it any more.

Comment: It is probably worthwhile saying that your examples are massively different:  **Virginity** and **Homosexual** are still widely used and are unlikely to cause offence – at least in the UK. **Nigger** (usually referred to as "the N-Word") is quite different. The general feeling here is that the word should not be used at all. It is about as bad as you can get. Even the use among the Black community is questionable as it is provocative to some other communities who feel that their “free speech” has been taken away.

Comment: I think Archaic should be posted as an answer.

Comment: I don't think any of these words are archaic; perhaps they are better described as politically incorrect, depending on who you ask. All are commonly used in America, althought as mentioned the N-word is reserved mostly for the AA community.

Comment: Convoluted censorship.  One generation, entity, etc, forcing its view on the others.  The mistaken view that if we are all the same, then we are all right.  Sure, there is misusage, such as slander, and, calling fire in a theater.

Comment: While it is true that the three words are now used less often than in the past (although they are not archaic or obsolete, in the usual sense), the reasons are not the same for all three. It is thus debatable whether there is a single phenomenon here, for which one could expect there to be a term.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Greybeard, it is true that different English-language cultures (not just different countries, but just simply different areas) have different views of the same word. I myself learned in a Canadian uni course on sexuality that homosexual is now generally considered offensive due to its historical associations with violence against gay people.

Comment: As for “nigger”, afaik in most North American countries, it is an acceptable slang amongst friends of the same race though more acceptable if black people use it amongst themselves, though currently it also seems less commonly used as a slang than perhaps many years ago.

Comment: It seems like the general consensus is the best word is “archaic”. jsw29 pointed out that there may be no single phenomenon amongst my word examples...would there be preferred a discussion, or does “archaic” sound reasonable enough as an answer?

Comment: “Outdated” “ancient” “defunct” “discontinued” and “antediluvian” might also be good candidates. Though I’m still deciding if there is one word that can cover the most context when used to describe such terms.

Comment: I’m sure “politically incorrect” covers some terms, but not all because 1) not all politically incorrect terms were once acceptable in history and 2) not all politically incorrect terms are being driven out of usage in formal literature.

Comment: The problem with *archaic* is that it is usually used for words that are not only rarely used, but also unlikely to be understood (except by those who have special interests in history). All three words that you have presented as examples are, however, well understood by the average present-day speakers of English. Also, there is vast difference between the words that may be used less often than in the past because of what they are **associated** with (the first two examples), and the words that are avoided because of something that is built into their **meaning** (the third example).

Comment: You are absolutely right, the reason I am hesitant about “archaic” is because of the “not used anymore”. Same with “obsolete”.

Comment: Of the words above, “ancient” doesn’t imply a word with bias; “antediluvian” seems a bit too informal; “outdated”, “defunct” and “discontinued” has a similar problem to “archaic”; I think a closer description would be something along the lines of “defected”, like “this word is now defect due to its historical connotations”...but doesn’t imply it’s yet completely unused. The problem is “defect” sounds rather strong coming on.

Answer (score -1):

I would term this
"lexical arhaism" or  just "archaism".

According to [Cambridge Dictionary:](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/archaism)
"A word or expression that is not generally used any more".

Comment: That may be the answer to the question formulated in the title, considered by itself, but the body of the question makes it clear that the OP is really asking something else.

Comment: @jsw29 Usually (as here) a fair criticism, but if there is a real opportunity for interesting analysis opened up by just one of the title / body questions in some of these ambiguously-presented questions, I think either is fair game.

Answer (score -1):

When you hear some of these terms used you usually hear it from older people who at the time of their childhood, the terms mentioned above might have been socially acceptable in general use.
So I have used the term *geriatricly inappropriate* to describe some of the words used by my grandfather, Lord rest his soul

But to address your second point about it being driven out of use you could reverse the term *Youthfully appropriate*